# Web Scraping into Excel

Tags: excel, web-services, web-scraping, import

I would like to create a spreadsheet that I can refresh and pull in each weeks English premier League fixtures, each week I would like to refresh this and see the weeks future fixtures. I have tried to use the import function from Data/From Web and selected the box with the table of fixtures however no data gets pulled into the spreadsheet.

The website I am using is - "http://data.7m.com.cn/matches_data/92/en/index.shtml"

I am open to understand a better way of doing this import and also if there is a better website to use I am also happy to change. I have chosen this one as it seems to have the most simplified listing of the fixtures.
I have also tried this website - https://www.premierleague.com/fixtures
When the import completes it actually skips all the fixtures and returns all the other information.
Should i be looking to some of the HTML elements within the script of the web page to extract the data?

For example on the following site - https://www.premierleague.com/fixtures I am looking for a file received by the website that updates the fixtures each week (after some direction from Google) I hit the F12 command and look within the "Network" tab however I cant understand how the website, this or the others quoted create the weekly fixtures. 
Any suggestions on how to pull this into Excel or another tool would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

*Welcome to [so]!*  it sounds like you haven't done as much research as you could have. Your first link, in the top corner has links to "Free Feed" which take you to customizable widgets and from there is a link to a customizable live template.The first page also has a link to "Data" , I'm not sure what that consists of or whether it will help (since I'm not much of a sports fan on *my* continent, and even less on yours!

As for importing into Excel, I didn't have an issue with the table I could see, but once again I'm not clear on what data you're trying to get and what you want to do with it.

1. On the ribbon's `Data` tab click <kbd>`From Web`</kbd>.
2. Enter the [first `URL`](http://data.7m.com.cn/matches_data/92/en/index.shtml) from your question and hit <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>
3. When the Navigator window loads, click **"Table 1"** and then click <kbd>`Load`</kbd>.
   Below is what Excel then automatically loaded as a table:

   [image: img]

If instead of clicking <kbd>`Load`</kbd>, you were to click <kbd>`Edit`</kbd> then you are brought into the Power Query Editor, where you can customizable tons of stuff.  The one I was interested in was `Use First Row on Headers`.  After choosing that, and clicking <kbd>`Close & Load`</kbd>, and 30 seconds of formatting later I had:

[image: img]

With **Power Query** you can choose, remove, split, or combine columns from this or other tables.  It's fairly advanced but you should be able to find a good **Power Query tutorial** online, to see examples of what you can do, to learn about other ways you can customize the import and/or analysis of the data.

---

<sub>Edit:</sub>

### More Information:

Here are the instructions for **all versions**:

- Office Support : [**Connect to a web page** (Power Query)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-a-web-page-power-query-b2725d67-c9e8-43e6-a590-c0a175bd64d8#ID0EAAEAAA=Office_2010)

Comment: I am using is - "http://data.7m.com.cn/matches_data/92/en/index.shtml" and when I try to import and get a message saying there is no data to import. I also dont have a "Load" option (Excel 2010) I see import or Go.

Comment: @Stephen :  I edited to add [a link](https://support.office.com/article/connect-to-a-web-page-power-query-b2725d67-c9e8-43e6-a590-c0a175bd64d8#ID0EAAEAAA=Office_2010) with instructions in all versions.

Comment: Way back in Excel 2010 eh, that's unfortunate; lots has changed . . .  Just so you know, if you're a [student](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/education/products/office/default.aspx) or a [developer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev-program), you can get a **free** copy of Office 365 (soon to be [Office 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2019)!), direct from Microsoft, with no strings (full version - not a trial, no strings).

Comment: Well downloading this addin has solved my problem thanks to you both ;-)